# How to write an API that allows PUT value in the url itself

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have the below classes:

**Models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(mex_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    @action(methods=['PUT'], detail=True)
    def update_department(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
        obj = self.get_object()
        ??
```

```
class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('department', )
```

Now I have 2 users in my database:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "abcd",
    "email": "abcd@gmail.com",
    "department": "accounts"
}
```

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "efgh",
    "email": "efgh@gmail.com",
    "department": "HR"
}
```

I want to update the department for user 2 to "accounts" with an api as below where I pass the value to be update with the api url itself:

PUT "/api/user/2/update_department/accounts"

How can this be achieved with DRF?

**Urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include

from rest_framework import routers

from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'user', views.UserViewSet, base_name='user_view')

slashless_router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
slashless_router.registry = router.registry[:]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'', include(slashless_router.urls)),
]
```